# SQuirrel_SQL_Client_3.7.1 unable to connect to SQL server 2016 SSL error

Tags: sql-server, squirrel-sql

we have migrated to SQL server 2016 and getting issue with SQuirrel_SQL_Client_3.7.1 connection as SSL error. SSL is not enforced on SQL server. From web i found we have to upgrade to SQL driver 4.2 or later. Currently we are using JDBC SQL Driver 4 and was working with SQL 2008 R2. We could make connection successfully from SQL server Mgmt studio client with ssl enabled. Please advise if anyone else had same issue.

Comment: Which Java version are you using to run Squirrel, and which version of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Hi Mark, just checked it is using java 1.7 This is part of Squirrel package. I am using sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: Hi Mark, i just changed the JRE version from 7 to 8 as i had JRE8 into my desktop and modified the Startup scripts for Squirrel and post that it is working fine.